# Byte -> Primitive inconsistency, attempting to create a buffer

Tags: java, io

I'm attempting to make a customized buffer that's going to be using a `List<Byte>` and currently I've only gotten as far as a single method before it completely broke down on me, and I'm not sure exactly why. I've been referencing the Source code of the [DataOutputStream](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.java.html) and [DataInputStream](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/DataInputStream.java.html) classes to make sure that I'm reading/writing the data correctly.

I must be doing something wrong.

```
    private List<Byte> buffer = new ArrayList<>();

    public void writeInt(int value) {
        buffer.add((byte)((value >>> 24) & 0xFF));
        buffer.add((byte)((value >>> 16) & 0xFF));
        buffer.add((byte)((value >>> 8) & 0xFF));
        buffer.add((byte)((value >>> 0) & 0xFF));
    }

    public void readInt() {
        int ch1 = buffer.get(0);
        int ch2 = buffer.get(1);
        int ch3 = buffer.get(2);
        int ch4 = buffer.get(3);

        System.out.println("CH1: " + ch1);
        System.out.println("CH2: " + ch2);
        System.out.println("CH3: " + ch3);
        System.out.println("CH4: " + ch4);
        System.out.println("===============");

        int value = ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
        System.out.println("Value: " + value);
    }
```

If I write a small value(Anything from 0->127), it's perfectly fine, however the moment I get to 128, all hell breaks lose, here's the output of 127vs128

**#writeInt(127)**

```
CH1: 0
CH2: 0
CH3: 0
CH4: 127
===============
Value: 127
```

**#writeInt(128)**

```
CH1: 0
CH2: 0
CH3: 0
CH4: -128
===============
Value: 128
```

**And just for some more (I don't understand it) examples, here's a large number.**
**#writeInt(999999999)**

```
CH1: 59
CH2: -102
CH3: -55
CH4: -1
===============
Value: 983156991
```

I'm honestly not sure where I'm going wrong, hopefully someone can tell me.

EDIT: I also thought it could be because I'm getting the byte as an int, and then trying to do the math, so I changed it up, but it didn't change the result at all. Modification example:

```
public void readInt() {
    int ch1 = buffer.get(0) << 24;
    int ch2 = buffer.get(1) << 16;
    int ch3 = buffer.get(2) << 8;
    int ch4 = buffer.get(3) << 0;

    System.out.println("CH1: " + ch1);
    System.out.println("CH2: " + ch2);
    System.out.println("CH3: " + ch3);
    System.out.println("CH4: " + ch4);
    System.out.println("===============");

    int value = (ch1 + ch2 + ch3 + ch4);
    System.out.println("Value: " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `byte` in Java is signed, like all primitive types with number semantics (`char` is the sole exception, but I wouldn't call `char` number semantics anyway). And Java, like the vast majority of devices, uses two's complement to store values.

Therefore the value range of byte is `-128` to `127`, here's a few of the corresponding 2's complement bit patterns that would be stored in a byte:

```
-128 -> 1000 0000
-127 -> 1000 0001
  -2 -> 1111 1110
  -1 -> 1111 1111
   0 -> 0000 0000
   1 -> 0000 0001
 126 -> 0111 1110
 127 -> 0111 1111
```

When you cast `byte` to `int`, and that's what happens implicitly when you do `buffer.get()` because you do arithmetic with the return value, it happens in a sign-extending way - that's how it's defined in Java.

In other words:

```
             (int) 128 ->  128 (0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  1000 0000)
      (byte) (int) 128 -> -128 (---- ----  ---- ----  ---- ----  1000 0000)
(int) (byte) (int) 128 -> -128 (1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1000 0000)
```

You want to negate the effects of sign-extension explicitly. You can do so by using `& 0xFF` before you shift the value. The corresponding part of your `readInt()` method should be like this:

```
    int ch1 = buffer.get(0) & 0xFF;
    int ch2 = buffer.get(1) & 0xFF;
    int ch3 = buffer.get(2) & 0xFF;
    int ch4 = buffer.get(3) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Very informative post, however I assumed that by writing the byte using ` buffer.add((byte)((value >>> 24) & 0xFF));` wouldn't make it so when I was reading I wouldn't have to do the same thing again? Looking at the DataInput/Output stream classes, this is the case.

Comment: It's not the same thing, because still a `Byte` is a `byte`. `(-1 & 0xFF)` is `255`, but `(byte) (-1 & 0xFF)` is `-1`. Which means your `& 0xFF` while disassembling the `int` into `byte`s and storing is redundant resp. in the wrong place, it needs to be done during assembly of the `int` while reading.